# How do I grab the Date that a Channel's Lastest Video Was Uploaded?

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to grab the date that GoogleDeveloper's latest video was uploaded. The problem is that I'm not sure how to grab it.

I'm trying to create a program where every time GoogleDeveloper's channel uploads a video an LED light attached to a breadboard on my Pi 3 will light up. I'm trying to do this by having a program check if the date of upload of their latest video has changed.

This is the code I have so far

```
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "/home/pi/Documents/client_secret_952042969529-4pdbg60vq9f0lnmsl7cahah9mrrts1pa.apps.googleusercontent.com.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part="snippet",
        maxResults=1,
        playlistId="UU_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)
    print(response.items);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I thought that if I printed "response.items" that I could grab the date that way, but it just prints out `<built-in method items of dict object at 0x75a14ed0>`

Comment: try changing `response.items` to `response.items()`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Get the uploads playlist id of the channel

Via https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list with the `contentDetails` part.

Step 2: Get the videos in the playlist

Via https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list with the `snippet` part.

Grab the video id of the first item.

Step 3: Get the video info including the publish date

Via https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list with the `snippet` part.

My answer is not down to the code so it’ll take you some time to get it working. But know that this is how it works in my production system.